# Python - imprimir os elementos da lista que têm 5 letras

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Boas,
Tendo a seguinte lista:

```
lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria','Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre',]
```

Quero imprimir  os elementos da lista que têm 5 letras.

Acontece que não estou a conseguir.

```
lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria',
'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre',]


for elem in lista_nomes:
   if elem == 5:
       lista_valida.append(elem) 
print (elem)
```

Comment: O que queres é verificar se a string (nome) tem 5 caracteres, não se `nome == 5`, isso sabemos que não vai ser. Usa `len()` para ver o comprimento (quantos caracteres) da string

Comment: Pois...eu achar que assim ia dar!

Comment: E acho que também tens de declarar `lista_valida = []` antes do for

Comment: Sim, tenho! erro meu nao o ter feito!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

```
lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre',]
nomes = [nome for nome in lista_nomes if len(nome) == 5]
print(nomes)
```

Veja [funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CanineJointAggregators)